# How to delete a row from DevExpress Grid

Tags: datasource, devexpress, xtragrid

I bind my DevExpress XtraGrid to a SQL Server database. I use the default navigator to delete rows. I would like the database to reflect these deletions as well. How do I do this?

Erik

Answer (score -1):

You should enable the ASPxGridView GridViewCommandColumn.

Here's an example using the Object Datasource but the concept is the same for any type.

```
<dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="False" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Projects">
    <DeleteButton Visible="True">
    </DeleteButton>
    <ClearFilterButton Visible="True"></ClearFilterButton>
</dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

And have the aproppiate Datasource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyDS" runat="server" 
        DeleteMethod="Delete"
        TypeName="Model.DataRepository">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: The question is about XtraGrid (WinForms) not ASPxGridView :-)

Comment: Opps... then you should use DeleteSelectedRows method :)